# How do I retrive the details of a Friend using his faceBook ID in android

Tags: java, android, json, facebook

I need to retrieve the details of a contact like Name, birthday, location and email id bu using the facebook id.
please help me, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant get friend's email, phone (private data).. but you can get all information which havent privacy like name, employee, school...etc.

for get information of friend so try this..

```
Facebook.request("id");
```

where id is your friend's id..

Comment: this is giving following error:-
GET URL: {"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"You can only access the \"home\" connection for the current user."}}?access_token=115515961865982%7C3fffdc33431032bac578eaaa.3-100001025926863%7Cb_75eC-omT5Iqad0jiWoPZ1G5sw&format=json